# How can I get common value from sets using MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with ID, AID and Year field. How can I find the latest common year among the sets (common AIDs makes a set)

```
ID  AID Year
---------
1   1   2001
2   1   2002
3   1   2003
4   1   2004

5   2   2003
6   2   2004
7   2   2005

8   3   2004
9   3   2005
10  3   2006
```

Latest common year  2004

Comment: If i understand it correctly you want to have the greatest Year where it's used in every AID?

Comment: Yes, correct. I want the max of common years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the most easy way of doing it.

**Query**

```
    SELECT 
      Year
    FROM 
     t
    GROUP BY 
     Year
    HAVING 
     COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.AID) FROM t)
```

**Result**

```
    | Year |
    | ---- |
    | 2004 |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ktsBzB9MEUQTcsBhUGVG1t/1)

This query makes it more visible why it works

**Query**

```
SELECT 
     Year
  ,  COUNT(*) AS count_per_AID
  , (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.AID) FROM t) AS unique_count_per_AID
  , (COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.AID) FROM t)) AS most_common_value
FROM 
 t
GROUP BY 
 Year
```

**Result**

```
| Year | count_per_AID  | unique_count_per_AID | most_common_value |
| ---- | -------------- | -------------------- | ----------------- |
| 2001 | 1              | 3                    | 0                 |
| 2002 | 1              | 3                    | 0                 |
| 2003 | 2              | 3                    | 0                 |
| 2004 | 3              | 3                    | 1                 |
| 2005 | 2              | 3                    | 0                 |
| 2006 | 1              | 3                    | 0                 |
```

> This query returns all the common years and not the latest common
>   year.

Indeed forpas thanks for making that comment. 
The fix would be to use the query

```
SELECT 
  Year
FROM 
 t
GROUP BY 
 Year
HAVING 
 COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.AID) FROM t)
ORDER BY 
 t.Year DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ktsBzB9MEUQTcsBhUGVG1t/2)

Comment: @SamikChattopadhyay i've updated mine answer because off forpas comment..